# Change value in cell based on date

Tags: excel

Just need help with something which might sound a bit unusual.

I've made an activity tracker on which i want the value in a specific cell to change when the date changes. That specific cell contains a timer (countdown timer). Now i want to change/update the value of the cell (countdown timer) only when the date changes. However the cell (countdown timer) should display the current value and should not update/change when the the date is same or Today's date, no mater if the workbook is closed by error or because of any other reason.

I'll try to explain with an example of what i want exactly.

Suppose cell "A1" in "Sheet1" displays the value "01:00:00" and current date is 16/08/2020. Now, due to an error or some reason the workbook closes on its own. Now what i want is, when the workbook is opened again, the value of the cell A1, on which the countdown timer is set, to display the current value on which the workbook was closed automatically.

And when the date changes, suppose tomorrow, 17/08/2020, the value of cell "A1" should reset/ change back to "01:00:00"

The value of cell "A1" should only reset when the current date changes to a future date.

I hope i was able to explain my question properly. Anyone please help me with this.

A VBA code or any formula will do. I'm using Excel Version 2003, as i've made the tracker for work purpose.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't actually asked a question. You are describing some behaviour, but you have not posted your code and you have not explained where you are stuck. Please edit your question, post your code, and explain what is not working. If you don't have any code, you're in the wrong web site. This is not a free coding service.